# Are there composite numbers that can stump this Pocklington variant?

Tags: prime-numbers

**Related question**: [Determine N primality knowing ALL factors of (n-1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038757/determine-n-primality-knowing-all-factors-of-n-1). But note that, unlike that question, I'm not searching for primes. I'm verifying a claim from a possibly mischievous source. I do care about the worst case.

So, let's say someone presents a claimed prime $p$ and the prime factorization of $p-1$. We have checked (recursively) that the factors are indeed prime, and now we check the claim that $p$ is prime.

**Plan A** (not serious, just to clarify what comes after): Lucas primality test:

> Pick $w$ at random.
>
> Check that $w^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, if not, then $p$ is composite, so reject.
>
> For each prime $q_i | (p-1)$, check that $w^{(p-1)/q_i} \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$, if so, then $p$ is prime, so accept.
>
> Otherwise, try another $w$.

This is a non-deterministic algorithm. But if it terminates, it always gives the right answer; and, for any $p$, with probability 1, it eventually terminates.

Now, if $p$ is actually prime, I figure the number of Lucas witnesses is $\phi(p-1)$ so the expected number of attempts would be $$E = \frac{p-1}{\phi(p-1)}$$ Wikipedia tells me that $$ \frac{N}{\phi(N)} < e^\gamma \log \log N + \frac{3}{\log \log N} $$ for $N>2$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. More concretely, I figure the worst cases are when $p-1$ is the product of the first $M$ primes. For example, I found that for $M=457$, we have a prime number $p_{457}$ with 4500 or so bits, for which the expected number of attempts is $$E \approx 14.5$$

Now, what if $p$ is not actually prime? Some comedian could give us a Carmichael number with 3 large prime factors. If we persist we will *eventually* stumble upon a number not coprime to $p$ and reject, but the expected number of attempts is going to be astronomical, $O(2^{n/3})$. In that sense this test can be 'stumped', even if it can't be 'fooled'.

**Plan B**: somewhat generalized Pocklington test:

> Pick $w$ at random;
>
> If $w^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$ then $p$ is composite.
>
> Otherwise for each prime $q_i | (p-1)$
>
> > calculate $g_i = \gcd(w^{(p-1)/q_i} - 1, p)$
> >
> > If $g_i=1$, then cross $q_i$ off the list of prime factors.
> >
> > If $g_i\not\in\{1,p\}$, then it is a non-trivial divisor of $p$, so $p$ is composite.
>
> If we've crossed out all prime factors $q_i$, then $p$ is prime.
>
> Otherwise try another $w$ (but only retest the $q_i$ that survived the previous attempt).

So the expected number of attempts for any prime factor is $q_i/(q_i-1)$, they're being checked in parallel, and subsequent attempts require fewer modular exponentiations. I actually verified $p_{457}$ this way, it took 462 modular exponentiations. I figure the expected number of modular exponentiations is $$E \le 2(k+1)$$ where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $p-1$, and with equality for a Fermat prime (where $k=1$, it reduces to Plan A).

**Main Question**: What happens in Plan B if $p$ is composite? Are there still numbers a comedian could use to make it take an unreasonably long time? (I tried some Carmichael numbers with three large prime factors, and it seems to find non-trivial divisors rather promptly.)

**Bonus Question**: if there are no "comedic" numbers, does anyone know what are the worst-case composite numbers?

Comment: Nice question! How is an "unreasonably long time" defined? Do you have a specific asymptotic result you wish to show?

Comment: "unreasonble" is longer than it takes for the Toronto Maple Leafs to win the Stanley Cup...... I don't know, I don't have a particular asymptotic bound in mind, but "not exponential time, like in plan A". Maybe within a couple of orders of magnitude of what it would take to confirm a prime number of similar size, for sizes up to, let's say $2^{2^{16}}$. (Which is not an asymptotic bound at all.)

Comment: (actually I would be surprised if the answer to the main question really depended on the exact definition of "reasonable"!)